# Magento 2 overriding Block Class Function

Tags: adminhtml, reports, dashboard, magento2.2.2, override-block

I just want to override `vendor/magento/module-backend/Block/Dashboard/Orders/Grid.php`
I added this line `$collection->addAttributeToFilter("status",["neq"=>"failed"]);`
Core overriding is successful but it doesn't effect admin dashboard.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: development
 * Date: 19.01.2018
 * Time: 08:54
 */

namespace Example\OrderStatistics\Override;


use Magento\Backend\Block\Dashboard\Orders\Grid;

class PassFailedOrders extends Grid
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        if (!$this->_moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_Reports')) {
            return $this;
        }
        $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->addItemCountExpr()->joinCustomerName(
            'customer'
        )->orderByCreatedAt();

        if ($this->getParam('store') || $this->getParam('website') || $this->getParam('group')) {
            if ($this->getParam('store')) {
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', $this->getParam('store'));
            } elseif ($this->getParam('website')) {
                $storeIds = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite($this->getParam('website'))->getStoreIds();
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', ['in' => $storeIds]);
            } elseif ($this->getParam('group')) {
                $storeIds = $this->_storeManager->getGroup($this->getParam('group'))->getStoreIds();
                $collection->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', ['in' => $storeIds]);
            }

            $collection->addRevenueToSelect();
        } else {
            $collection->addRevenueToSelect(true);
        }
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter("status",["neq"=>"failed"]); // This is added 

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

}
```

And here is my di.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Backend\Block\Dashboard\Orders\Grid" type="Example\OrderStatistics\Override\PassFailedOrders"/>
</config>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

I found what is problem. in Magento\Backend\Block\Dashboard\Orders\Grid Class there is _prepareCollection() function. And when I override this function it just returns to again same class. But I need to return Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid _prepareCollection() function. How do I ?

Comment: remove return parent::_prepareCollection(); from your function and return as         return $this->setCollection($collection);

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code,

call `parent::_prepareCollection($collection);` before executing your code

```
use Magento\Backend\Block\Dashboard\Orders\Grid;

class PassFailedOrders extends Grid
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
    parent::_prepareCollection();

    if (!$this->_moduleManager->isEnabled('Magento_Reports')) {
        return $this;
    }
    $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->addItemCountExpr()->joinCustomerName(
        'customer'
    )->orderByCreatedAt();

    if ($this->getParam('store') || $this->getParam('website') || $this->getParam('group')) {
        if ($this->getParam('store')) {
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', $this->getParam('store'));
        } elseif ($this->getParam('website')) {
            $storeIds = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite($this->getParam('website'))->getStoreIds();
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', ['in' => $storeIds]);
        } elseif ($this->getParam('group')) {
            $storeIds = $this->_storeManager->getGroup($this->getParam('group'))->getStoreIds();
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('store_id', ['in' => $storeIds]);
        }

        $collection->addRevenueToSelect();
    } else {
        $collection->addRevenueToSelect(true);
    }
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter("status",["neq"=>"failed"]); // This is added 

    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return $this;
    }

}
```